# What complexity .equals() is in immutable.js

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, immutable.js

I'm comparing two deeply nested immutable Maps in **immutable.js**. 
What is the complexity of the [`.equals()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/equals) function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Immutable js source code, the key places that implement equality are  [deepEqual.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/6b6074677ae986c92c793673ceb958bc130a76c2/src/utils/deepEqual.js) and [is.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/6b6074677ae986c92c793673ceb958bc130a76c2/src/is.js).

The equality performs a recursive comparison into the map and does the comparison exactly once for each node. Thus the complexity of the comparison is O(n).